# How to force Jest to see nested javascript function?

Tags: javascript, jestjs, create-react-app

I have such structure in my project

```
|...
|Utils
    | Utils.js
    | Utils.test.js
|...
```

In `Utils.js` I have func, I want to test:

```
export const getSurroundingCells = (numRows, numCols, shipPositions) => {
    ...
    // some logic that calls cellIsSuitable()
    ...
    const cellIsSuitable = (position, shipPositions) => {
        ...
        // some logic that uses numRows, numCols
        ...
    }
}
```

When I want to test it via `Jest` with `Utils.test.js`:

```
import {getSurroundingCells} from "./Utils";

const shipPositions = [[1, 1], [1, 2], [1, 3]];
const expectedSurroundingCells = [[2, 1], [2, 0], [1, 0], [0,0], [0,1], [0,2], [2,2]];

test('takes positions and returns surrounding cells', () => {
    expect(getSurroundingCells(10, 10, shipPositions)).toBe(expectedSurroundingCells);
});
```

I get:

> ReferenceError: cellIsSuitable is not defined

How can I force `Jest` to see my nested function `cellIsSuitable` ?

P.S. My project bootstrapped `with create-react-app`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move it up to the top or make it a regular `function` so that it's hoisted. The function is assigned after you use it but the variable is declared.

```
export const getSurroundingCells = (numRows, numCols, shipPositions) => {

    const cellIsSuitable = (position, shipPositions) => {
        ...
        // some logic that uses numRows, numCols
        ...
    }

    ...
    // some logic that calls cellIsSuitable()
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It helped!